# Problems in removing compile time errors-Springs MVC

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, compiler-errors

I am a novice springs programmmer and I have just completed reading my springs mvc 3.0 concepts.I tried writing my first code in springs but I am facing problems in removing compile time errors.The errors are shown on these lines

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;
```

The Error shown is

```
The import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired cannot be resolved
```

and same for other `import`
My files placements I think are proper

All the jar files are placed as

[image]

I am unable to think on the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write some application in spring and understand how it works you can download spring tool suite and follow this tutorial:
http://manueljordan.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/creating-a-spring-web-mvc-project-with-springsource-tool-suite/

Answer (score 1):

Note 1: If your are using Linux system you should org.spring.framework.xxx-Sources jars.

Note 2: if you are using Windows system you should use org.spring.framework.xxx-Releases jars

Hope this will help you.

for Note you can refer:[Difference between Binary release and source release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280906/difference-between-binary-release-and-source-release)