# Julia BinDeps: Difference between Sources and Binaries

Tags: julia, naming, binaries

I am trying to use BinDeps to download a package dependency. After reading the documentation I am still a little confused over the difference between Sources and Binaries.

Can someone explain how they are different?
If I just want to download a .so file from a specified URL, and have it placed in usr/lib, which one should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280906/difference-between-groovy-binary-and-source-release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `Sources` are for downloading the actual source code of a project which would then use a BuildProcess or SimpleBuild to compile. `Binaries` is for downloading pre-compiled shared libraries.

Comment: That would make sense. Thank you