# Advantages of source release over binary release?

Tags: software-distribution

I now understand the major differences between source release and binary release of a software. A good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280906/difference-between-binary-release-and-source-release).

I needed to install Node.js on a Linux machine, and chose binary release because it requires no compilation/installation. I downloaded the tar, unzipped the file, and it's ready-to-go.

My question is, when both choices are available, **for what reasons would a person choose source over binary?**

The only thing I can think of is that the person wishes to read/study the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a source release when:

- There are no pre-compiled binaries for your [platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_architectures). You have to build them yourself.
- You want to compile it into your project.
- You want to make changes (although you'd better be using [git](https://github.com/nodejs/node) for that).
- You want to comply to the open source license when using it in your product.
  Eg: with [gpl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) you must provide the source when someone asks.

Comment: If I were installing it locally I doubt I'd be as fussed with someone asking to see my machine to see that source code.