# Confluent Platform error while starting zookeeper - Classpath is empty

Tags: windows, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I downloaded [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/) in my local windows machine & tried to start zookeeper, but it is giving me below error:

```
c:\confluent>.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\etc\kafka\zookeeper.prop
erties
Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running 'gradlew jarA
ll'
```

Comment: thankks Peter, but i am getting above error while setting confluent-kafka.

Comment: The problem occurs when you download and use source downloads instead of binary downloads.

Comment: @Valentina There is no such thing

Comment: @OneCricketeer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280906/difference-between-binary-release-and-source-release

Comment: @Valentina Uh. That's Groovy. What's your point? You can't do that for Confluent Platform

Answer (score 0):

Confluent does not test their products on Windows, last I heard.

The recommendation is to install WSL or use the Confluent Docker containers.